# Angular 2 - Add submitted form flag to FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Is there anyone who have tried to add a property to the FormGroup class. I want to add a submitted property that will be set on the submit of the form because I want to show form errors only after submit. The easiest way is to add a variable in the component that will be set to true on submit, but I don't like this.

If we extends FormGroup, would it be possible to do something?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

**First** set `temp variable` on the `<form>` tag **>>** `myForm`.
Now, when the form is *submitted* the `myForm.submitted` will be set to `true`.

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(ngForm)">
  ...

  <!--  hide if not submitted  -->
  <div [hidden]="!myForm.submitted">
    Error Message!
  </div>
  ...
</form>
```

Good Luck.